# TCP and UDP connections (simultaneously) python3

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, udp

I don't want to bother you with my long boring code so I will explain the
bottom of my problem , I'm writing a Messenger program it has global chat , it has personal messaging (same chat but only addressed client will see it) and on top of this it supposed to have
a simple file transfer from the server (already known files inside the server) to every client
who desires this files.
so my basic architecture is TCP connection based message sending and inner language

example : `[Josh]<Kristine> : Hello`

means : josh sends to kristine "Hello" and only she can see it

for the file transfer part I need to use UDP and notice that I have to keep my TCP
connection working

example : `[Josh]<>&WantsDownload& (filesPath\sendme.txt)!DownloadsPath\receiveme.txt?`

so I send &WantsDownload& request via TCP the server notice and enters a function
now I need to send via UDP I tried to open another socket using same port and address
it didnt work and I tried to change the current TCP socket to UDP and it didn't work

would like some help guys Im really lost

Edit :
small code just in case , this two are from inside each ones functions

CLIENT.PY

```
serverUDP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
serverUDP.bind((HOST, UDPPORT))
data = serverUDP.recv(1024)
print(data)
serverUDP.close()
```

SERVER.PY

```
serverUDP = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
serverUDP.bind((HOST, UDPPORT))
print(" is now downloading")
filename = NameOfRequesterFile
file = open(filename,'rb')
file_data = file.read(1024)
print(file_data)
serverUDP.sendto(file_data,HOST)
print("File is downloaded successfully")
serverUDP.close()
```

edit2:
I also tried to use different port for this UDP connection , the problem accures when I use th sendto command from my udp socket , and most of my errors are this: OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner self.run() File "C:\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 946, in run self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)

also tried changing in client form serverUDP.recv to serverUDP.recvform and same error

Comment: UDP has no guarantee of delivery

Comment: How you are sending and receiving data via UDP may work on an optimal network link or small files, but sending a large file over a link that does not work perfectly will fail due to the missing flow controls in UDP.

Comment: its a really small file 1kb size a text file that conatains "0000000000000000" thats it , I just need a way to receive something in UDP doesnt matter even a massage , I tried to do it in a seperate Thread it didnt worked either :(

Comment: It is rather strange that you need to transfer a seemingly static information via UDP explicitly. Please explain!

Comment: university networking project , they told us explicitly what they want

Comment: Unfortunately the stacktrace you show has no relation to the code you show, so it is not clear where it is failing. Also `serverUDP.sendto(file_data,HOST)` is clearly wrong since it is missing the destination port. And there is no need to bind the sending UDP socket. *"I don't want to bother you with my long boring code"* - please write a minimal but working program which is sufficient to show the problem you are facing. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: solved it , UDP should run inside infinite loop (server side) so that it transmit constantly until I catch the data with my client thanks guys   :)